# Fast way to convert std::list of pointer to std::list of value

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a `std::list<obj*>`, where `obj` is my class:

```
std::list<obj*> list_of_ptr;
list_of_ptr.push_back(new obj());
```

I want to convert this list to the equivalent `std::list<obj>`, after that I no longer need the `list_of_ptr`.
What is the fastest way to do this work?

Comment: Why do you have a container that owns pointers in the first place?  The preferred solution would be to use a container of `obj` from the start.  What criteria did you use to select `std::list`?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis you're right but I can't change this for now.

Comment: Unless it is _impossible_ to change the code (e.g., it's part of an interface that other software components rely on and thus change is impossible), it would be far simpler to rewrite the code using automatic lifetime management (i.e., avoid explicit `new` and `delete`) than to try to make your manual memory management correct.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11335738/1395740) is the problem.

Comment: Storing pointers in a container like this is almost always unnecessary and a bad idea.  Let the container manage your objects for you, that's what it's good at.

Comment: @EdS. So, if you have a better idea follow my link and aswer my qustion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::transform` is your friend:

```
std::vector<obj> objects;
std::transform(
    list_of_ptr.begin(), list_of_ptr.end(),
    std::back_inserter(objects), 
    [](obj* p) { return *p; });
```

Or, if C++11 lambda expressions cannot be used, one may use a simple function object to perform the indirection:

```
struct indirect
{
    template <typename T>
    T& operator()(T* p) { return *p; }
};

std::transform(
    list_of_ptr.begin(), list_of_ptr.end(),
    std::back_inserter(objects), 
    indirect());
```

Or, using [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html):

```
std::vector<obj> objects(
    boost::make_indirect_iterator(list_of_ptr.begin()),
    boost::make_indirect_iterator(list_of_ptr.end()));
```

These, of course, assume that there are no null pointers in the sequence.  It is left as an exercise for the reader to figure out how to correctly manage the lifetimes of the objects pointed to by the pointers in `list_of_ptr`.

Ideally, one would use a `std::vector<obj>` from the start, or, if that is not possible, a container of smart pointers.  Manually managing the lifetimes of the pointed-to objects, and doing so correctly, is very difficult.  C++ has awesome automatic object lifetime management facilities (destructors, smart pointers, containers, stack semantics, RAII), and there is no reason not to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Simplicity and code that is easy to understand is also your friend:

```
for each (obj* pObj in list_of_ptr)
{
    if (pObj != nullptr)
    {
        list_of_objects.push_back(*pObj);
    }
}
```

And if that doesn't compile for you, this certainly should:

```
std::list<obj> list_of_objects;

for_each(list_of_ptr.begin(), list_of_ptr.end(), [&list_of_objects] (obj* pObj) {
    if (pObj != nullptr)
        list_of_objects.push_back(*pObj);
});
```