# Create std::list of value instead of std::list of pointers in recursive function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, c++11

I have this class:

```
class obj
{
public:

    obj()
        : parent(nullptr),
        depth(0)
    {   }

    obj* parent;
    list<obj> children;
    int depth;  // Used only for this example
};
```

And to fill my data structure I use a recursive function like the following:

```
void recursive(obj& parent)
{
    if(parent.depth == 1)
        return;

    obj son;
    son.parent = &parent;
    son.depth = parent.depth + 1;

    recursive(son);

    parent.children.push_back(son);
}
```

In this way for example:

```
obj root;
recursive(root);
```

If you pay attention you can see that if the test in the recursive funcion had been:

```
if(parent.depth == n)
    return;
```

with `n >= 2` this code will not work  (the stored address of the parent of the "grandson" `root->son->son` - and so on - will be not a valid address once you exit the recursive function).

One way to solve this problem is use a list of pointers (`list<obj*> children`) instead a list of value:

```
void recursive(obj& parent)
{
    if(parent.depth == 2)
        return;

    obj* son_ptr = new obj();
    son_ptr->parent = &parent;
    son_ptr->depth = parent.depth + 1;

    recursive(*son);

    parent.children.push_back(son_ptr);
}
```

Is there another way to do the same work and store the `obj`s in a list of value instead of in a list of pointers?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a factory for object creation?

Comment: It is a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Have a "factory" object that creates the `obj`s and maps an internally held unique ID for each object to its current pointer.  Each `obj` could keep a reference to the factory object, and during the copy constructor tell the factory the new address and invalidate the old one.  Then you can keep a parent ID and ask the factory for its pointer whenever you need it.

Comment: I don't think I can use, but i'm not sure because I never used a "factory" before... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Nick: you don't know how to do something, someone suggests something that's sounds promising, saying "I don't think I can use it [because I haven't done it before] / thanks anyway" is really dismissal and unappreciative and counterproductive - if you'd solved this problem before you wouldn't be asking it now.  Why don't you instead say "sorry for the hassle but I don't know how to implement what you're suggesting, could you give me a bit more help?".

Comment: @TonyDelroy I thought it was obvious, I'll really appreciate an example.

Comment: @tmpearce can you make me an example?

Comment: As it stands the problem is ill-defined.  We don't know why you're trying to do what you're saying you want.  We don't know the requirements - what can be changed and what can't.  If you clarify the problem, I could make a short example, but until then I'm not going to guess at what would or wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it just a matter of fixing the address of the objects before you start creating further children?  To do that, put them into the children list first, then recurse...

```
void recursive(obj& parent, int n)
{
    if (parent.depth == n)
        return;

    obj son;
    son.parent = &parent;
    son.depth = parent.depth + 1;
    parent.children.push_back(son);

    recursive(parent.children.back(), n);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a valid answer +1 but i can't change the order of my instructions for now.

Comment: @Nick: Telling us you can't do something like that without explaining why makes it very hard to propose solutions.  Still, I'll throw another out there which may or may not be reordering from your perspective: you could omit setting `son.parent` in `recursive()`, instead count the depth using an extra function parameter to which 1 is added on each recursive call, then have a second function that goes back down through the structure and fills in the `.parent` pointers after `recursive()` has unwound, copying the values into their final list locations.

Comment: Be patient... I'm trying to do my best with the real code that is "a little bit" more complicated... If i can adjust my code with your solution i'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider storing unique IDs in the `obj`s, such that the instance of the `obj` doesn't define the represented object's identity but rather its ID does. If you do this, you could potentially store the ID to link related `obj`s instead of storing pointers.

For instance, you could change the `obj` class to include an `int` field `id`:

```
class obj {
public:
    obj()
        : parent(nullptr),
          depth(0)
    {
        // Not thread-safe; would need to get protected if multi-threaded
        id = nextId++;
    }

    static int nextId;

    int id;
    int parentId;
    list<int> childrenIds;

    int depth;  // Used only for this example
};
```

Whenever you construct a new `obj` to represent a new logical "thing", you can assign a new, unique value to the `id` field. When you want to establish a relationship between `obj`s that represent related "things", you can--for instance--use a `parentId` field instead of a `parent` pointer field:

```
void recursive(obj& parent)
{
    if (parent.depth == 1) {
        return;
    }

    obj son;
    son.parentId = parent.id;
    son.depth = parent.depth + 1;

    recursive(son);

    parent.childrenIds.push_back(son.id);
}
```

This requires more work when you want to follow the link: instead of following the pointer to the parent `obj`, you'd instead need to look up the `obj` in some global `obj` list you maintain (searching for the `parentId` in question).

Of course, this really depends on what these `obj`s are really representing, and the broader goals you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what you mean, Can you make me an exampe?

Comment: @Nick I've provided some more details, but left it fairly abstract. Does this help?

Comment: Umh... I don't think that your answer can help me to make a list of value :(

Comment: @Nick What makes you think that? My answers addresses the concern about broken pointers to invalid objects -- with what I suggest, you wouldn't have pointers, and thus nothing to get broken. Perhaps I didn't explain it well enough if you think that...

Comment: Try to answer in C++ instead of in english, perhaps this can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help +1, your solution may works but i need to have a list of obj value.