# How to know if a std::list has been modified

Tags: c++, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create std::list of value instead of std::list of pointers in recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335738/create-stdlist-of-value-instead-of-stdlist-of-pointers-in-recursive-function)

I have this class:

```
class C
{
public:

    C* parent;
    std::list<C> children;
};
```

I can use this class in this way for example:

```
C root;
C child;

root.children.push_back(child); // or other method of std::list (es: push_front, insert, ...)

// Here child.parent is root
// How can I set the parent of child?
```

I want to do this work internally to my class without losing the functionality of `std::list`, is it possible?

Comment: Note that you're pushing a copy of `child`.

Comment: @ybungalobill yes you're righ, I want to set the parent of the child inserted in the list

Comment: Please match the title and your actual question.

Comment: Why would you mark your other identical question as answered then ask the same question again?

Comment: @ildjarn Ahah! are you kidding?

Comment: How about creating the copy of the list and comparing it with the possibly modified original one?

Comment: Also note that this code is *undefined-behavior*: You use an incomplete type `C` as a template parameter for a standard container.

Comment: @Nick : No, I'm not kidding. The answer to that question _exactly_ answers this one. Did you even read it?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the title of the question and the question itself. What are you actually asking?

Comment: @ildjarn do you see the recursive fucntion here?

Comment: @Nick : I see you attempting to populate a list of children with the correct parent set. Gee, no, not similar at _all_.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
class C {
public:
    C* parent;
    std::list<C *> children;
    explicit C(C *p = 0) : parent(p) {
        if (p) p->children.push_back(this);
    }
};

C root;
C child(&root);
```

Note that I changed your `children` list to take pointers. This is fine as long as `C` is not expected to manage the memory for the nodes, just refer to them.

The title of your question was: *How to know if a std::list has been modified*. From your comments, it seems like what you want is a *proxy*:

```
class ListProxy {
    std::list<C *> children;
public:
    // replicate list traits
    // ...

    void push_back (C *c) {
        children.push_back(c);
        //... do something
    }

    void erase (iterator i) {
        children.erase(i);
        //... do something
    }

    //...
};
```

The proxy delegates list functionality to the list, but augments behavior for those methods that would change the list.

```
class C {
public:
    C* parent;
    ListProxy children;
    explicit C(C *p = 0) : parent(p) {
        if (p) p->children.push_back(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: If I add the `add_child` method I loose all the functionality of the `std::list` if I make it private, and If I don't I can always use the `push_back` method and invalid my data structure.

Comment: @Nick: I am not sure what your concern is. Are you afraid of some other programmer accessing the `children` list and maliciously adding children?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement interface functions in your class. For example:

```
class C
{
private:
    std::list<C *> children;
public:
    C* parent;

    void AddChild(C *child);
};
```

Then, just do this in the AddChild function:

```
void C::AddChild(C *child)
{
     children.push_back(child);

     // Do internal work here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add one member function:

```
class C
{
    C* parent;
    std::list<C> children;  //make it private first
public:
    void add_child(C const & child)
    {
         children.push_back(child);
         children.back().parent = this; //make `this` child's parent
    }    
};
```

Comment: In this way I loose all functionality of std::list

Comment: @Nick: You can expose those functions as member functions. I think that will be better, as it gives you an opportunity to choose proper name for them (which also matters), in addition to adding new functionalities, such as the one shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Since you seem to have linked list on your own, you could just add a `AddChild` method to your class. This can use the std::list functionality.

I'm quite sure that you don't want to store values but pointers to C, as you possibly
do not want to copy your C every time you add it to the list.

```
public:
void AddChild(C *child)
{
    this.children.push_back(child);
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
C *root = new C();
C *child = new C();
child->parent = root;
root->AddChild(child);
```

You can set the parent in the AddChild also, which gives you some chance of having
coherent lists (each child has a proper parent set).

But, if you are interested in changes, use the **Observer pattern**.

Here is an article on that, c++ code samples are included there: [Observer pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)

Comment: His list is of type `C` not of `C*`

Comment: Think he wants to change that. What do you think?

Comment: Quite possibly, I just think you should perhaps mention that you have changed the type of the object in his list.

Comment: edited for clarification